# Using Twig with ACF Flexible Content - Having trouble getting variable to work for tax_query

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

Im not that great with Twig. So I'm sure I am doing something stupid...

Im trying to be able to select a custom taxonomy with ACF inside a flexible content page builder and pull in the posts from CPT "Featured Work." If I remove the tax query, it pulls in all posts. If I use the conditional

```
if category.id == departmentt
```

it will pull in fine but only if the post ONLY has the selected taxonomy checked and nothing more. I need to be able to pull in all posts that have a certain category checked even if it has multiple categories checked.

Controller

```
<?php
$context = Timber::context();

$timber_post     = new Timber\Post();
$args = ['posts_per_page' => 3, 'post_type' => 'post'];
$context['news'] = Timber::get_posts( $args );

$context['team'] = Timber::get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'team',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
       // 'meta_key' => 'last_name',
       // 'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    )
);

$context['location'] = Timber::get_terms('location');
$departmentt = get_field('focus_areas_and_capabilities2');

$context['work'] = Timber::get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'Featured Work',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'location',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => '45',
            )
        ),
));

$context['post'] = $timber_post;
Timber::render( array( 'page-capabilities.twig' ), $context );
```

Template

```
<section>
{% set departmentt = layout.focus_areas_and_capabilities2 %}

{{departmentt|join(', ') }} - {{location|join(', ') }} - {{work|join(', ') }}

{% for post in work %}
    <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
    {% include ['tease-team.twig'] %}
{% endfor %}
</section>
```

Everything shows up the way I need it when I use `{{departmentt|join(', ') }}` on the front end

Instead of

```
'field' => 'term_id', 'terms' => $departmentt,
```

I've tried using:

```
'field' => 'term_id', 'terms' => '45', //This is the ID of my test category
```

This works but I need this ID to change based on the selected taxonomy.

I've also tried using:

```
'field' => 'name', 'terms' => $departmentt,
```

I changed the ACF field to be field Object and it works with the category name as well but wont with the variable even though it shows correctly on the front end.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is it right to assume you want to display certains items *after* an user checked some options? If so then you will need to resort to javascript and use ajax to fetch the new items.

Comment: Apologies. I need to select a taxonomy in the backend in the ACF flexible content page build. Once that category is selected, and the page is saved, I need it to bring in all posts from a CPT with that category selected on the front end of the page.

Comment: I basically need to know why this isnt working: $departmentt = get_field('focus_areas_and_capabilities2'); as a variable in the tax query. The field is correct and I can use it in the template but not in the controller